# Google App Engine - update_indexes error

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Java app deployed on app engine and I use appcfg.py of the
Python SDK to vacuum and update my indexes.

Yesterday I first ran vacuum_indexes and that completed successfully -
i.e. it en-queued tasks to delete my existing indexes.

The next step was probably a mistake on my part - I then ran
update_indexes even though my previous indexes weren't yet deleted.
Needless to say that my update_indexes call errored out. So much so
that now when I look at my app engine console, it shows the status of
all my indexes as "Error".

A day has passed an it still shows the status on my indexes as "Error".

Can someone help my out of my fix?!

Thanks,
Keyur

P.S.: I have posted this on the GAE forums as well but hoping SO users have faced and resolved this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I followed what was suggested in the error logs and that worked for me:

1. Empty the index.yaml file (create a backup first)
2. Run vacuum_indexes again
3. Look at your app's admin console and don't go to the next step till all your indexes are deleted.
4. Specify the indexes you want to be created in index.yaml
5. Run update_indexes
6. Look at your app's admin console and it should show that your indexes are now building.
7. Enjoy the fruits of your labor :)

Cheers,
Keyur