# Confirmation before removing all unused index in the datastore (GAE / Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing

I have a website in production, and I would like to avoid doing a big mistake...
I would like to use vaccum index command

> ./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes myapp/war

Does a backup can help restoring all indexes ?
Have you any recomendation before doing this kind of operation ?
Here is my datastore-indexes.xml:

```
<datastore-index kind="Event"   ancestor="false" source="manual">
<property name="date_list"      direction="asc" />
<property name="e_name"         direction="asc" />  
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="U"       ancestor="false" source="manual">
<property name="u02_name"       direction="asc" />
<property name="u04_zona"       direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="S"       ancestor="false" source="manual">
<property name="cookie"         direction="asc" />
<property name="dateCreated"    direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

Here is a screeshot of my current indexes status (in red, are the indexes I should actually use):
[image]
Thanks you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Searching StackOverflow for this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-app-engine%5D%20vacuum) [[image]google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) tag and vacuum indicates that other users often do vacuuming but do not report any data loss, so you should be all right.  [One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024663/google-app-engine-update-indexes-error) contains a good warning about an action you should avoid, namely doing update_indexes before vacuuming is complete (probably asking for eventual consistency trouble), and the upvoted answer describes a sensible recovery procedure.

To get some confidence you could use the [Admin Console](https://appengine.google.com/), Datastore Admin page to copy all your data to another app and perform all your maintenance work there first.  The data volumes shown should copy fairly quickly.  The copy will give you peace of mind and would also be a handy warm standby backup in case the unthinkable happens to you production data.